# Factor the RSA modulus $n = 3844384501$ knowing that $3117761185^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

As per the title, the task is to

> Factor the RSA modulus $n = 3844384501$ knowing that $$3117761185^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}\text{.}$$

$n$ being an "RSA modulus" means that it is a product of two primes, i.e. $n = pq$.  The task is to find these two primes.

I can see that from what we're given,
$$
(3117761185 - 1)(3117761185 + 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}\text{,}
$$
but I do not know how to proceed from there on.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**N.B.** It would seem that computing $\gcd(3117761184, n)$ and $\gcd(3117761186, n)$ would give me $p$ and $q$ but I have no idea why that would be justified.

Comment: Well.. from the congruence you wrote up we can conclude that $p$ and $q$ are among the union of prime divisors of 3117761184 and 3117761186.

Comment: You have found $a, b$ such that $ab = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ you don't care about.

Comment: @Berci: Why can we conclude that?  All I am able to conclude is that $p q \mid  3117761184 \cdot 3117761186$; my background in number theory is probably lacking.

Comment: @d125q Since $p$ and $q$ are *primes*, each of them divides either $3117761184$ or $3117761186$.

Comment: @rogerl: Thanks a lot.  Would it be fine to say that given $a, b$ s.t. $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, we have that $ab \mid c \Leftrightarrow a \mid c \wedge b \mid c$?

Comment: @d125q Yes, that is correct as well.